# Is it safe to always use torch.tensor or torch.FloatTensor? Or do I need to treat Ints with care?

Tags: pytorch

> https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

I am trying to understand the difference between `tensor, FloatTensor, IntTensor` - and am wondering if I can just always stick to `tensor`... or maybe `FloatTensor`.

I am going to be using a mix of different tensors that will be:

```
{integers:labels, floats:continuous, one-hot-encoded:categoricals}
```

Do I need to explicitly set each of these as kinds of variables as different types of tensors? Will they all work as floats? Will they work in combination with each other?

---

Would this get me into trouble downstream?

```py
l_o_l = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

int_tnz = th.FloatTensor(l_o_l)
int_tnz
```

```py
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.]])
```

```py
>>> int_tnz.dtype
torch.float32
```

---

```py
l_o_fl = [[1.1,2.2,3.3],[1.1,2.2,3.3],[1.1,2.2,3.3]]

int_tnz = th.tensor(l_o_fl)
int_tnz
```

```py
tensor([[1.1000, 2.2000, 3.3000],
        [1.1000, 2.2000, 3.3000],
        [1.1000, 2.2000, 3.3000]])
```

```py
>>> int_tnz.dtype

torch.float32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CrossEntropyLoss` (or `NLLLoss`) expect the `target` type to be `Long`. For example, the code below raises a `RuntimeError`:

```py
import torch.nn 

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

predicted = torch.rand(10, 10, dtype=torch.float)
target = torch.rand(10) #.to(torch.long)
criterion(predicted, target)
# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

You need to uncomment the conversion to make it work. I cannot think of a bigger issue, but why bother converting the integers to float in the first place?

Regarding the use of `torch.tensor` and `torch.FloatTensor`, I prefer the former. `torch.FloatTensor` seems to be the legacy constructor, and it does not accept `device` as an argument. Again, I do not think this a big concern, but still, using `torch.tensor` increases the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to use `FloatTensor` on all kinds of dtypes.

Can't average integer tensors, which makes sense.

```
a = th.tensor([1,1])
b = th.tensor([2,2])

th.mean(th.stack([a,b]))
```

`RuntimeError: Can only calculate the mean of floating types. Got Long instead.`